# Symfony 2 Dependency Injection "must be an instance of" (constructor may be being passed in nothing.)

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I am currently trying to do dependency injection of one class into another for my bundle.
I am trying to base it on the examples given within the Symfony2 documentation about the Newsletter / Mailer.
I currently get this error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error:
Argument 1 passed to Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass::__construct()
must be an instance of Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\FirstClass\FirstClass,
none given
```

MyBundle.php

```
namespace Me\MyBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Resources\component\FirstClass;
use Resources\component\SecondClass;

class MeMyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container
            ->register('first_class', 'FirstClass');

        $container
            ->register('second_class', 'SecondClass')
            ->addArgument(new Reference('first_class'));
    }
}
```

/Resources/component/FirstClass.php

```
<?php
namespace Me\MyBundle\Resources\component;

class FirstClass
{
    ....
}
```

/Resources/component/SecondClass.php

```
<?php
namespace Me\MyBundle\Resources\component;

class SecondClass {    

    private $firstClass;

    public function __construct ( FirstClass\FirstClass $firstClass ) {
        $this->firstClass = $firstClass;
    }
    ....
```

Any ideas as to where it is going wrong? I get the impression that the new Reference('first_class') is passing in nothing.
I am assuming, using the method above, nothing needs to be added to my services.yml

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** (This is what I had to do, to get it to work)

MyBundle.php

```
$container
    ->register('first_class', 'Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\FirstClass');

$container
    ->register('second_class', 'Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass')
    ->addArgument(new Reference('first_class'));
```

SecondClass.php

```
public function __construct ( LanguageCodes $langCodes )
```

It was mainly a fight with name spaces.

Thanks to the patiences of Cerad, I finally got it sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have this:

```
$container = new ContainerBuilder(); ?
```

$container is passed as an argument.  And I have a sneaking suspicion that you are not using the container to get your object.

Are you doing this somewhere:

```
$instance = $this->container->get('second_class");
```

or are you trying:

```
$instance = new SecondClass();
```

Comment: I have removed the ContainerBuilder() line. Thanks for that. And yes, I was doing $instance = new SecondClass(); within my Controller. Having removed that line, it does now load the page without error. But I am guessing it will error when I try and make such calls to it.

Comment: Yep.  You need to use the container to make your objects.  From inside a controller, $this->get('second_class'); will do the trick.

Comment: If I add this to the controller: $sc = $this->container->get('second_class'); it gives this error: "Class 'SecondClass' not found in /public_html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 1291"

Comment: I did also try $this->get('second_class'); but it returned the same error.

Comment: The line is doing this: "new \SecondClass($this->get('first_class'));" so I think I have a namespace issue there.

Comment: Have tried: Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass\SecondClass but that doesn't work. Am I right in thinking that these classes of mine have to sit within the Vendor folder? as that is where all the other namespaces in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php are pointing.

Comment: You need to specify the full class name when you register the objects. ->register('second_class', 'Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass\SecondClass')

Comment: This is what I have done: $container->register('second_class', 'Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass\SecondClass');

Comment: Which creates: protected function getSecondClassService(){return $this->services['second_class'] = new \Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass\SecondClass();} in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php

Comment: And if you just do new \Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass\SecondClass(); what happens?  It is a bit strange that you put these classes under Resources.

Comment: Doing \Me\MyBundle\Resources\component\SecondClass\SecondClass(); within my controller works fine. The documentation for Symfony didn't indicate where you stick your own classes, since it wasn't a controller itself, I didn't really know where to put it. So I just stuck it with my other resources. To be honest, I don't mind where it sits.

Comment: I am open to suggestions as to where my classes should live.